# Removing line breaks in Python output

Tags: python, split, nltk

I am cleaning a text file and have written the following code to remove unwanted characters.  My issue is that the final output appears as a list of words, when I want it composed as a text.  I think the issue is in this line which is intended to remove line breaks by replacing new line i.e. "(\n)" with ""

```
Step4 = re.sub(r"(\n)"," ",Step3)
        print(Step4)
```

Full code as follows:

```
f=open("/Applications/Python 3.9/cleaning text.txt",encoding='Latin-1')
raw=f.read()
#print(raw)
import re
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
Data = re.split(r" ",raw)
for D in Data:
#    print(str(raw)+'\n')
    Step1 = re.sub(r"(\\.*)","",D)
#    print(Step1)
    Step2 = re.sub(r"(M)","hl",Step1)
#    print(Step2)
    Step3 = re.sub(r"(\[aa\])","[a::]",Step2)
#    print(Step3)
    Step4 = re.sub(r"(\n)"," ",Step3)
    print(Step4)
```

Comment: Could you share the text in the `cleaning text.txt` file

Comment: In the line 'Data = re.split(r" ",raw)'  you are creating a list of strings. You should be able to replace the unwanted symbols directly on  the string raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need split whole text into list word by word. You can give raw data as an input to ***re.sub()*** function. If you want to remove space character from beginning or ending of raw data, you can use ***strip()*** function for this.

```
f=open("/Applications/Python 3.9/cleaning text.txt",encoding='Latin-1')
raw=f.read()
import re

raw = str(raw).strip()
Step1 = re.sub(r"(\\.*)","",raw)
Step2 = re.sub(r"(M)","hl",Step1)
Step3 = re.sub(r"(\[aa\])","[a::]",Step2)
Step4 = re.sub(r"(\n)"," ",Step3)
```